# How to get the list of remote files under a Dir and iterate over to list out the contents via ansible

Tags: ansible-2.x

Does anyone knows how to get the list of remote files under a particular Dir and  to iterate over them and list out the contents of each file via ansible?
For example , i have a location `/var/spool/cron` and  it has many files which i need to `cat <file>` by iterate over each of them.

`fileglob` and `lookup` works locally.

Below is the play but not working as expected.

```
---
- name: Playbook to quick check the cron jobs for user
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: cron state
    shell: |
      ls /var/spool/cron/
    register: cron_status
  - debug: var=item
    with_items:
        - "{{ cron_status.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as an example

```
 ---
  - name: Playbook
    hosts: all
    become: root
    gather_facts: False
    tasks:
    - name: run ls-
      shell: |
        ls -d1 /etc/cron.d/*
      register: cron_status

    - name: cat files
      shell: cat {{ item }}
      register: files_cat
      with_items:
        - "{{ cron_status.stdout_lines }}" 

    - debug: var=item
      with_items:
        - "{{ files_cat.results| map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake you someones Intrest..
Below Play will give you more cleaner stdout

```
---
- name: hostname
  hosts: all
  become: root
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: checking cron entries
    shell: more /var/spool/cron/*
    register: cron_status
  - debug: var=cron_status.stdout_lines
```